# Modify path of execution of a python script running as a windows service

Tags: python, windows-services, py2exe, configparser

I have a Python application that uses `ConfigParser.ConfigParser()` to access a configuration file. I have created a windows service of the Python application using `py2exe`. The problem that I have is that the service can only find the configuration file if I place it in `windows/system32` folder. I would like to have the configuration file in the same folder where the service was installed. For example, after using `py2exe` I have the following folder:

```
c:/temp/dist/winservice.exe
c:/temp/dist/configfile.cfg
```

Then I do:

```
winservice.exe install
```

But the service does not look for the `configfile.cfg` in path: `c:/temp/dist/` but in path: `c:/windows/system32/`

Is there any way to change that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Inspect module to get the name of the file in which this code object was created.
So to get the path of the file you will use : `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename`

So, to get a directory name where your winservice.exe is:

```
dirPath = os.path.dirname(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_filename)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Alexander. I have already tried your suggestion and `dirPath` is empty. I am doing `configFile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dirPath),'config.cfg')` and configFile is equal to "config.cfg". The thing is that the service only find the file if I place it inside c:/windows/system32/ path.